# Search if a String has a subset string present in array of object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, substring

Looking for the optimal solution to find a string inside an array of objects.

Let's say I have a variable that holds a ***result*** which I get from an API call

```
let result = "485178485451478"
```

I have to search the above ***result*** in the below array of objects & see if the substring in the array matches the ***result***. If the ***result*** matches I simply want to return true.

```
const arrayCode = [
      {
        "code": "2150"
      },
      {
        "code": "4857"
      },
      {
        "code": "5046"
      },
      {
        "code": "4851"
      },
      {
        "code": "4154"
      },
      {
        "code": "9654"
      },
      {
        "code": "1254"
      },
      {
        "code": "9562"
      },
      {
        "code": "1457"
      },
      {
        "code": "6479"
      }]
```

So here in the above problem if I write a code, it should return me an index of ***3***.

Below is the basic code which I wrote to get the solution. But what if the array length is too long? Looking for the optimal solution. Thanks

Below is the code:

```
let result = "485178485451478"
let index = 0
for(let i= 0; i< arrayCode.length;i++){
    let flag = result.indexOf(arrayCode[i].code);
    if(flag===0){
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

console.log(index)
```

Comment: its just `arrayCode.findIndex(({code}) => result.startsWith(code));` to return the index, or replace `findIndex()` with `some()` for a boolean return. This is a duplicate i just need to find it.

Comment: You can't avoid looping through the entire array. If it's long, too bad.

Comment: @pilchard Actually `array.findIndex(...)`

Comment: @Barmar ;) edited. Though the OP also says they just want to return `true` if found so maybe `some()`

Comment: @pilchard Good point, but in that case `index = i` doesn't do it, because they initialized `let index = 0`. There's no way to distinguish finding it in the first object and not finding it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this requirement with a single line of code with the help of [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method along with [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Live Demo **:**

```js
let result = "485178485451478";

const arrayCode = [
  {
    "code": "2150"
  },
  {
    "code": "4857"
  },
  {
    "code": "5046"
  },
  {
    "code": "4851"
  },
  {
    "code": "4154"
  },
  {
    "code": "9654"
  },
  {
    "code": "1254"
  },
  {
    "code": "9562"
  },
  {
    "code": "1457"
  },
  {
    "code": "6479"
  }
];

const res = arrayCode.some(({ code }) => result.indexOf(code) !== -1);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `some` function will iterate only until it finds the first occurrence, so you could use along with the `includes` function:

```js
const included = (element) => result.includes(element.code);
console.log(arrayCode.some(included));
```

Answer (score 0):

here is What I would do:

```
let index = 0
arrayCode.forEach((e, indx) => {if(result.indexOf(e.code) == 0)index = indx;});
console.log(index)
```

Hope to help!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).